# Can the unit displayed in the transfer rate meter in pv be changed?

Tags: pv

In `pv`, the rate meter is displayed as

```
47.5MiB 0:00:00 [ 165MiB/s] [================================>] 100%
```

where the unit used for the transfer stats is `MiB` (1024 bytes). Is it possible to change this unit to `MB` (1000 bytes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about Linux is that you have access to the sources, so it is pretty much always possible to change something to do what you would like it to do, if you make the effort.

In this case, it is not too difficult to download the sources, and look through them to see if it is obvious what to  change. Then just rebuild your own `pv` binary. If you are using an `rpm` based system try the following (as an ordinary user):

```
$ yumdownloader --source pv
```

(This should work even if you have dnf instead of yum). You should end up with a file with suffix `.src.rpm`. The rest of the name will vary depending on your release. Install and compile it:

```
$ rpm -i pv-1.6.0-1.fc22.src.rpm
$ rpmbuild -bc ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/pv.spec
```

You don't need to be root to install the sources as they are put in `~/rpmbuild`. You may however need to install the `rpmbuild` and other packages to do the compilation. You should get the normal final binary pv in:

```
$ file ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/pv-1.6.0/pv
```

Grep through the sources, for say MiB, to find a likely change. I found `~/rpmbuild/BUILD/pv-1.6.0/src/pv/display.c` had a routine `pv__si_prefix()` that took a parameter `is_bytes` that determined whether to divide by 1000 or 1024. I simply edited this routine to force it to 0 by adding

```
is_bytes = 0;
```

just after the declarations (before `if (is_bytes) {`). Then do `make` to get the binary recompiled as follows:

```
$ cd ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/pv-1.6.0/
$ make
```

The new `pv` file should do what you want.

---

On a `deb` packaging system you have similar steps to do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev debhelper
$ apt-get source pv
$ cd pv-1.6.0/
$ dpkg-buildpackage -b -nc
  ...  edit src/pv/display.c
$ make
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I notice that some preloaded versions of `pv` output in megabytes while others output in mebibytes. Do you by any chance know why this is so?

Comment: I found an older version of the pv sources. It seems it always divided by 1024, but the output said "MB" instead of "MiB". In the `doc/NEWS` source file it mentions *improved SI prefixes* from version 1.2.0.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I'll need to update my `pv` then.